# How should we debug issues which come only while generating a production JS bundle in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I had to troubleshoot an issue which occurs only while building a production JS bundle in react-native. The build fails at the following step, :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets with some syntax errors. These syntax errors do not occur in the development bundle.

I want to know what are the best possible ways to debug these kind of issues.

I can give additional info regarding the specific problem I have if necessary.

Comment: Did it happen during `assembleRelease`, could you share more of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because the transpilation step has failed, you should invoke the bundle step manually:

```
react-native bundle \
--platform ios \
--dev false \
--entry-file index.ios.js \
--bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

So long as you've not made changes to the default entry/output location the command above should work.

If it is indeed the transpiling failing, this will show you the errors.